# How to crossfade between old and new image in Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using Glide for loading images in an adapter, the problem is when I modify and image in a new activity and return to thumbnail list and refresh screen, Glide cross fades between **placeholder** and **new image**. I want it to cross fade between **old image** and **new image**.

Comment: Unfortunately, Glide v4 doesn't support crossfade between images: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transitions.html#cross-fading-across-requests

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can add listener and you can receive callbacks.

```
.listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            // do something
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            // do something
            return true;
         }
    })
```